# How to get a json key that contains a specific string with jq?

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I have a json data like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "module": {
    "endpoint": {
      "mode": "pc",
      "protocolVersion": "2.0"
    },
    "reload": true,
    "data": {
      "leftContainer_CL": {
        "id": "CL",
        "tag": "leftContainer",
        "fields": {
          "css": {
            "floatPosition": "left",
            "width": "788px"
          },
          "tag": "leftContainer"
        },
        "type": "container"
      },
      "container_C": {
        "id": "C",
        "tag": "container",
        "fields": {
          "css": {
            "marginTop": "12px"
          },
          "tag": "container"
        },
        "type": "container"
      },
      "delivery_dfdaf8a8a": {
        "id": "dfdaf8a8a",
        "tag": "delivery",
        "fields": {
          "selectPos": "right",
          "deliveryBy": {
            "text": "Disediakan oleh",
            "poster": "ALL ITEM STORE"
          },
          "options": [
            {
              "highlight": false,
              "deliveryId": "STANDARD",
              "bgColor": "#fafafa",
              "price": "Rp18.900",
              "disable": false,
              "reachTime": "Dapatkan pada\n 3-4 Apr 2018",
              "liveUp": false,
              "selected": true
            }
          ],
          "style": "bar"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "rightContainer_CR": {
        "id": "CR",
        "tag": "rightContainer",
        "fields": {
          "css": {
            "floatPosition": "right",
            "width": "388px"
          },
          "tag": "rightContainer"
        },
        "type": "container"
      },
      "delivery_d43597338a": {
        "id": "d43597338a",
        "tag": "delivery",
        "fields": {
          "selectPos": "right",
          "deliveryBy": {
            "text": "Disediakan oleh",
            "poster": "incredible accessories hp"
          },
          "options": [
            {
              "highlight": false,
              "deliveryId": "STANDARD",
              "bgColor": "#fafafa",
              "price": "Rp37.800",
              "disable": false,
              "reachTime": "Dapatkan pada\n 3-4 Apr 2018",
              "liveUp": false,
              "selected": true
            }
          ],
          "style": "bar"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "orderSummary_6": {
        "id": "6",
        "tag": "orderSummary",
        "fields": {
          "isOpen": "false",
          "summarys": [
            {
              "tail": "(3 barang)",
              "title": "Subtotal",
              "value": "Rp23.557"
            },
            {
              "title": "Biaya pengiriman",
              "value": "Rp56.700"
            }
          ],
          "title": "Ringkasan Pesanan\r\n"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "root_0": {
        "id": "0",
        "tag": "root",
        "fields": {
          "count": 3,
          "title": "Troli belanja Saya"
        },
        "type": "root"
      },
      "item_i77997d6b": {
        "id": "i77997d6b",
        "tag": "item",
        "fields": {
          "img": "https://id-live.slatic.net/original/08c1396908dc240625751b09decb4211.jpg",
          "quantity": {
            "qtyPrefix": "Kuantitas",
            "min": 1,
            "autoOptions": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "max": 5,
            "editable": true,
            "showIncrDecr": true,
            "showOptions": false,
            "step": 1
          },
          "sellerName": "ALL ITEM STORE",
          "title": "Case Slim Black Matte Xiaomi Redmi 4A Softcase Black",
          "stockTip": {},
          "valid": true,
          "itemId": "143800088",
          "operations": [
            "wishlist",
            "delete"
          ],
          "sellerId": "100124080",
          "price": {
            "price": 6000,
            "currentPrice": "Rp6.000",
            "originPrice": "Rp30.000",
            "promotionRatio": "-80%"
          },
          "restriction": false,
          "isGift": false,
          "sku": {
            "skuText": "Softcase, Hitam",
            "productVariant": "SO908ELAAVYY4AANID-72544754",
            "brandId": "17818",
            "skuId": "157608391"
          },
          "itemUrl": "https://www.lazada.co.id/products/i143800088-s157608391.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1",
          "cartItemId": 2006547819
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "location_2": {
        "id": "2",
        "tag": "location",
        "fields": {
          "buttonText": "GANTI\r\n",
          "editable": true,
          "postCode": "",
          "style": "casAddress",
          "label": "Lokasi",
          "title": "Jawa Tengah,Kab. Boyolali,Ampel",
          "addressId": "R2388357-R80010396-R80015219"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "voucherInput_7": {
        "id": "7",
        "tag": "voucherInput",
        "fields": {
          "buttonText": "GUNAKAN",
          "placeHolder": "Masukkan Kode Voucher",
          "status": "default"
        },
        "type": "biz",
        "validate": {
          "value": [
            {
              "msg": "Maaf, voucher ini tidak dapat digunakan. Silahkan periksa jika ada kesalahan penulisan",
              "regex": "^$|^[ ]{0,5}[A-Za-z0-9~!@#%&*()_+？<>{}|-]{1,100}[ ]{0,5}$"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "shop_43597338a_s2c": {
        "id": "43597338a_s2c",
        "tag": "shop",
        "fields": {
          "badges": [],
          "link": "//www.lazada.co.id/shop/incredible-accessories-hp",
          "name": "incredible accessories hp"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "item_i7799f86e": {
        "id": "i7799f86e",
        "tag": "item",
        "fields": {
          "img": "http://id-live-02.slatic.net/p/2/case-anti-shock-anti-crack-elegant-softcase-for-xiaomi-redmi-5a-white-clear-free-tempered-glass-1273-94487227-9f8ddff53bde3f8de9eb514ba2172361-catalog.jpg",
          "quantity": {
            "qtyPrefix": "Kuantitas",
            "min": 1,
            "autoOptions": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "max": 5,
            "editable": true,
            "showIncrDecr": true,
            "showOptions": false,
            "step": 1
          },
          "sellerName": "incredible accessories hp",
          "title": "Case Anti Shock / Anti Crack Elegant Softcase  for Xiaomi Redmi 5A - White Clear + Free Tempered Glass",
          "stockTip": {},
          "valid": true,
          "itemId": "160714927",
          "operations": [
            "wishlist",
            "delete"
          ],
          "sellerId": "53631",
          "price": {
            "price": 13580,
            "currentPrice": "Rp13.580",
            "originPrice": "Rp25.000",
            "promotionRatio": "-46%"
          },
          "restriction": false,
          "isGift": false,
          "sku": {
            "skuText": "Softcase, Bening",
            "productVariant": "SO908ELAB716EPANID-97510528",
            "brandId": "17818",
            "skuId": "183461134"
          },
          "itemUrl": "https://www.lazada.co.id/products/i160714927-s183461134.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1",
          "cartItemId": 2006579310
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "package_p43597338a": {
        "id": "p43597338a",
        "tag": "package",
        "fields": {},
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "listHeader_H": {
        "id": "H",
        "tag": "listHeader",
        "fields": {
          "middle": "HARGA",
          "left": "3 barang",
          "right": "KUANTITAS"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "delivery_3": {
        "id": "3",
        "tag": "delivery",
        "fields": {
          "selectPos": "left",
          "options": [
            {
              "highlight": false,
              "deliveryId": "STANDARD",
              "bgColor": "#fafafa",
              "price": "Rp56.700",
              "disable": false,
              "icon": "https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1UpyCpfDH8KJjy1XcXXcpdXXa-72-72.png",
              "name": "Standar",
              "reachTime": "Dapatkan pada\n 3-4 Apr 2018",
              "liveUp": false,
              "selected": true
            }
          ],
          "style": "card",
          "title": "Pengiriman yang dipilih"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "orderTotal_8": {
        "id": "8",
        "tag": "orderTotal",
        "fields": {
          "button": {
            "enable": true,
            "text": "LANJUTKAN KE PEMBAYARAN",
            "clicked": false
          },
          "payment": {
            "taxTip": "Termasuk PPN, jika berlaku",
            "pay": "Rp80.257",
            "title": "Total"
          }
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "shop_fdaf8a8a_s23f9": {
        "id": "fdaf8a8a_s23f9",
        "tag": "shop",
        "fields": {
          "badges": [],
          "link": "//www.lazada.co.id/shop/all-item-store",
          "name": "ALL ITEM STORE"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "floatTips_4": {
        "id": "4",
        "tag": "floatTips",
        "fields": {
          "tips": []
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "item_i7790e0f9": {
        "id": "i7790e0f9",
        "tag": "item",
        "fields": {
          "img": "http://id-live-02.slatic.net/p/2/case-anti-shock-anti-crack-elegant-softcase-for-xiaomi-redmi-note4x-white-clear-8431-85175402-0bec01e88741744ae5461c4b3a4ae160-catalog.jpg",
          "quantity": {
            "qtyPrefix": "Kuantitas",
            "min": 1,
            "autoOptions": false,
            "quantity": 1,
            "max": 5,
            "editable": true,
            "showIncrDecr": true,
            "showOptions": false,
            "step": 1
          },
          "sellerName": "incredible accessories hp",
          "title": "Case Anti Shock / Anti Crack Elegant Softcase  for Xiaomi Redmi Note 4x - White Clear",
          "stockTip": {},
          "valid": true,
          "itemId": "108849535",
          "operations": [
            "wishlist",
            "delete"
          ],
          "sellerId": "53631",
          "price": {
            "price": 3977,
            "currentPrice": "Rp3.977",
            "originPrice": "Rp15.000",
            "promotionRatio": "-73%"
          },
          "restriction": false,
          "isGift": false,
          "sku": {
            "skuText": "Sarung, Bening",
            "productVariant": "CA529ELAAC6GUEANID-27304198",
            "brandId": "10464",
            "skuId": "110628148"
          },
          "itemUrl": "https://www.lazada.co.id/products/i108849535-s110628148.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1",
          "cartItemId": 2005983481
        },
        "type": "biz"
      },
      "package_pfdaf8a8a": {
        "id": "pfdaf8a8a",
        "tag": "package",
        "fields": {},
        "type": "biz"
      }
    },
    "hierarchy": {
      "component": [
        "container",
        "delivery",
        "item",
        "shop",
        "package",
        "listHeader",
        "orderSummary",
        "leftContainer",
        "orderTotal",
        "floatTips",
        "root",
        "location",
        "rightContainer",
        "voucherInput"
      ],
      "root": "root_0",
      "structure": {
        "package_p43597338a": [
          "delivery_d43597338a",
          "shop_43597338a_s2c",
          "item_i7799f86e",
          "item_i7790e0f9"
        ],
        "leftContainer_CL": [
          "delivery_3",
          "listHeader_H",
          "package_pfdaf8a8a",
          "package_p43597338a"
        ],
        "container_C": [
          "leftContainer_CL",
          "rightContainer_CR"
        ],
        "rightContainer_CR": [
          "location_2",
          "orderSummary_6"
        ],
        "orderSummary_6": [
          "voucherInput_7",
          "orderTotal_8"
        ],
        "root_0": [
          "container_C",
          "floatTips_4"
        ],
        "package_pfdaf8a8a": [
          "delivery_dfdaf8a8a",
          "shop_fdaf8a8a_s23f9",
          "item_i77997d6b"
        ]
      }
    },
    "linkage": {
      "input": [],
      "request": [
        "voucherInput_7",
        "item_i7799f86e",
        "delivery_3",
        "orderTotal_8",
        "item_i7790e0f9",
        "location_2",
        "item_i77997d6b"
      ],
      "common": {
        "compress": true,
        "queryParams": "^^$$1afe141216814f45e9fc6dba84d4863d{$_$}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",
        "submitParams": "^^$$f7898231e0216a924bcaa64d213a61ba{$_$}H4sIAAAAAAAAADXMQQrDMAwEwL/oHPSA3PqBUsgLto4bDJJtJPvS4L/XCfS2uwx7UoumKUNoPakK2qeY0ko10EIVR5w5wBqNhTI0bhXhv/kk3aM93NORr4MgcH9OdomiLPhiB9+YtexRuEuzkrnCoM5bf2tqr7vQGD8eVpdVjwAAAA=="
      },
      "signature": "89dffd9ca23307e603556a4c896e4c56"
    }
  }
}
```

With `jq` I can do this:

`[me@linux]$ cat /tmp/json | jq '.module | .data | keys'
[
  "container_C",
  "delivery_3",
  "delivery_d43597338a",
  "delivery_dfdaf8a8a",
  "floatTips_4",
  "item_i7790e0f9",
  "item_i77997d6b",
  "item_i7799f86e",
  "leftContainer_CL",
  "listHeader_H",
  "location_2",
  "orderSummary_6",
  "orderTotal_8",
  "package_p43597338a",
  "package_pfdaf8a8a",
  "rightContainer_CR",
  "root_0",
  "shop_43597338a_s2c",
  "shop_fdaf8a8a_s23f9",
  "voucherInput_7"
]`

I need to get `orderTotal_8` but please note that the number `8` is always changing, so it can be `orderTotal_10` or `orderTotal_3` etc... How can I get this key with pure `jq` command if possible, without the help of grep / awk ? So the result should be like this `orderTotal_8`

Comment: For future reference, please adhere as much as possible to the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to form a subarray of items satisfying some condition, just add map(select( CONDITION )) to the pipeline, e.g.

```
.module | .data | keys | map(select(test("^orderTotal_")))
```

If you just want a stream of the items matching the condition, then you could first form the stream, and then make the selection:

```
.module | .data | keys[] | select(test("^orderTotal_"))
```

For efficiency and other reasons, you might want to consider using `keys_unsorted` instead of `keys`.